# Why can't ServiceStack handle an exception from a method that returns Guid?

Tags: c#, exception, servicestack

Note: I confirmed that this issue occurs with ServiceStack 3.9.71.0 and 4.0.46.0.

Here is my extremely rudimentary service code:

```
namespace MyServiceStackApplication.Services
{
    [Route("/hello")]
    [Route("/hello/{Name}")]
    public class Hello
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

public class HelloService : Service
{
    public Guid Any(Hello request) // Note that this method returns a Guid.
    {
        throw new Exception("My test exception."); // Note that I am throwing an exception here.
    }
}
}
```

And here is my `Global.asax.cs` code:

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    public class AppHost : AppHostBase
    {
        public AppHost() : base("Hello Web Services", typeof(HelloService).Assembly) { }

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        //register any dependencies your services use, e.g:
        //container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
    }

    public override IServiceRunner<TRequest> CreateServiceRunner<TRequest>(ActionContext actionContext)
    {
        return new MyServiceRunner<TRequest>(this, actionContext);
    }

    public class MyServiceRunner<T> : ServiceRunner<T>
    {
        public MyServiceRunner(IAppHost appHost, ActionContext actionContext) : base(appHost, actionContext)
        {
        }

        public override object HandleException(IRequest request, T requestDto, Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            return base.HandleException(request, requestDto, ex);
        }
    }
}

protected void Application_Start()
{
    //AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    //FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    //RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    //BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    new AppHost().Init();
}
}
```

My Question:

- Why doesn't my `HandleException` method receive the thrown exception at the top of the stack trace when I call `http://localhost:xxxxx/hello`?[image]

Comment: What else do you expect from an inner exception?

Comment: I expect that `System.Exception` should be at the top of the stack trace because that's the thrown exception. Please see my screenshot.

Comment: and your screenshots shows the output of `.ToString()` call on an exception holding an inner exception - maybe you should unwind your exception, if you expect another outcome. Or did I completely lose the path?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair: I could unwind it (i.e. I could slice off the top layer of that stack trace and call it a day), but I want to understand why this is necessary. After all, ServiceStack is throwing this exception; not me.

Comment: It is still not clear to me whether you are trying to understand the "necessity" of wrapping your excpetion in a `TargetInvocationException`, or the reason why the `.ToString()` of an exception gives you this output.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair ServiceStack throws the TargetInvocationException. I want to know why.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only return a Reference Type from a ServiceStack Service which should ideally be a Response DTO but can also be a raw type like `string`, `byte[]`, `Stream`, etc.